# Different traceroute response times for same path

Tags: slow-connection, traceroute

When troubleshooting for slow Internet speed on one computer, I am having systematic slower response times between two computers when running tacert, for any domain.They are both connected to the same wifi network.

Both computers are running Windows 11. They are at the exact same distance of the router.

On the first :

```
tracert google.com

  1     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.0.1
  2   123 ms    159 ms    187 ms  modemcablexxx.xxx-162-184.mc.videotron.ca [184.162.xxx.xxx]
  3   23 ms    17 ms    18 ms  10.170.158.194
  4   15 ms    19 ms   16 ms  72.14.216.228
  5    26 ms    13 ms   21 ms  108.170.228.18
  6   21 ms    18 ms    10 ms  108.170.231.53
  7   40 ms    18 ms   244 ms  yul02s05-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.13.142]
```

On the second (the slow one) :

```
tracert google.com
  1    374 ms   3 ms     5 ms   192.168.0.1
  2    321 ms   13 ms    23 ms  modemcablexxx.xxx-162-184.mc.videotron.ca [184.162.xxx.xxx]
  3    *        322 ms   16 ms  10.170.158.194
  4    107 ms   27 ms    *      72.14.216.228
  5    136 ms   16 ms    15 ms  108.170.228.18
  6    417 ms   21 ms   470 ms  108.170.231.53
  7    348 ms   17 ms   437 ms  yul02s05-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.13.142]
```

Any idea how to explain this?

Comment: Explain what? The differences? CPU load? Memory Load? Network load? Except for the first hop they don't look dissimilar to me. Are you expecting them to be the same?

Comment: You definitely have a problem with Internet connections (most likely wifi). Both your computers have intermittent delays >300ms on the first two hops (last mile).

Comment: My bad, I actually posted two outputs from the slow computer. I edited the question to reflect actual observed values.

Comment: i still dont see a difference, end user question are odf topic